# Modal View Controller don't rotate correctly

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad

On the ipad, in ios objective C, I am having problems with the rotation moves in one modal view. I give the position of the element in the `shouldAutoRotate` method and its parent view can rotate too, but when I rotate the modal view the elements don't put in the correct place.

For more information, if I open the view in portrait mode I get this data:

```
<UIView: 0x72bc160; frame = (0 0; 768 1004); clipsToBounds = YES; 
autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x13f324f0>
```

And in landscape mode:

```
<UIView: 0x1358f3b0; frame = (0 0; 768 748); clipsToBounds = YES; 
autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x1358f3e0>>
```

But if I rotate the view the horizontal frame changes by vertical frame...

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: its hard for me to understand what the problem really is. did you try presenting the modal view from the root view controller?

Comment: check wether the control comes to shouldAutoRotate in modal view..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've had a lot of fun with view controller rotation. There are two things to keep in mind:

1. Assuming you're covering the entire screen (and don't do anything specific with subview transformation), make sure you are presenting the modal view controller from the broadest possible view controller, often the root view controller of the application.
2. Make sure every conceptual containing view controller passes along the rotation events to its conceptual child view controllers. (This was very ill-defined pre-iOS 5.)

When these things happened to me, it was because the view controllers in the background got the rotation events, but the particular view controller I was presenting from was ignoring them and not passing them along to the modal view controller, leading to inconsistency.

Comment: Thank you so much. I was putting the modal view in one view that was different of the root view :)

Comment: Another thing: you can run into unpredictable interface rotation issues if you present a modal view controller from another view controller that is *also* being presented modally. If you're presenting view controllers in a modal chain like this, it may be a sign of bad architecture anyway...

Comment: @EricGoldberg: The good thing is that if you always remember to present the view controller from the broadest view controller, that's always the "top-level" view controller, and you sidestep this problem.

Comment: @Jesper: Agreed. Sometimes when things don't "feel" right, you're shoehorning something in a way that Cocoa Touch doesn't like, and there's probably a few dozen reasons Apple made it the way they did. User interface-wise, a modal *probably* shouldn't be presenting another modal. A modal should represent a "dead end" or "leaf" in the user flow. Perhaps with nav controller hierarchy within itself, but not presenting another modal from itself.